# Magento 2 - Where is the best place to save temp files

Tags: magento2, structured-data

I need to save same temp file, now I'm using:

```
/**
*Magento\Framework\App\Filesystem\DirectoryList $directoryList
*/
$this->directoryList->getPath('media')
```

But I need same place where this files will be deleted same day.

**Where is the best place to put this files?**

Answer (score 1):

I think this **var**

```
protected $_dir;
protected $_filesystem;
...

public function __construct(
    ...
    \Magento\Framework\Filesystem\DirectoryList $dir,
    \Magento\Framework\Filesystem $filesystem

    ...        
) {
    ...
    $this->_dir = $dir;
    $this->_filesystem = $filesystem;
    ...
}

public method saveFile()
{
   ...
   {
      $var = $this->filesystem->getDirectoryWrite($this->_dir->getPath('var'));
      $content = 'something';
      $var->writeFile("folder/file.txt",$content);
   }
        catch(Exception $e){
        echo $e->getMessage();
    }
   ...
}
```

Comment: Using this folder ('var'), when I access the file with navigator I get an error. "You don't have permission to access /mysite/var/fileName.csv on this server."